# Displaying images from sql in php with next/prev buttons

Tags: php, sql, image

How can I alter this code so that It only displays one image at a time, with a next and previous button in order to browse through the images.

[I used the code from this website](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/76064-uploading-images-with-php/)

```
$sql = "select * from people";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " .  mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo "<div class=\"picture\">";
        echo "<p>";

// Note that we are building our src string using the filename from the database
        echo "<img src=\"images/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";
        echo $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'] . "<br />";
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</div>";
```

If no one is willing to help, can they point me in the direction of a tutorial or a website that may have the answers. I am new to php so all help is much appreciated.

Comment: what are you using to display the image? lightbox?

Comment: I hope to learn how to resize images within the code as opposed to resorting to lightbox This is how it currently looks: goawaymom.com/test2/images.php

Comment: do you just wanna display one image on the page or the whole gallery, and use lightbox to browse through them?

Comment: I want to display one image at a time; as mentioned I'd prefer not to use lightbox and rather just have the images resized within the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$page = $_GET['page'];    
$sql = "select * from people LIMIT $page,1";
while(...){
  ...
  $next_page = $page+1;
  $prev_page = $page-1;

  $next_btn = "<a href='script.php?page=".$next_page."'>Next</a>";
}
```

Here is a basic implementation, do not forget about negative/maximum verifications and mysql injection !

Comment: In response to: 'am i going to use lightbox?' I hope to learn how to resize images within the code as opposed to resorting to lightbox

This is how it currently looks: http://goawaymom.com/test2/images.php 

I'm going to try out the code that Dinu Rodnitchi gave me. Thanks for the quick responses guys, and if you're interested in results I'll keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

Image crop. You can pass the parameters in the url to get your desired output image size like this `image.php?src=img/random.jpg&w=300&h=200`

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_GET['src']);

$thumb_width = $_GET['w'];
$thumb_height = $_GET['h'];

$width = imagesx($image);
$height = imagesy($image);

$original_aspect = $width / $height;
$thumb_aspect = $thumb_width / $thumb_height;

if($original_aspect >= $thumb_aspect) {
   // If image is wider than thumbnail (in aspect ratio sense)
   $new_height = $thumb_height;
   $new_width = $width / ($height / $thumb_height);
} else {
   // If the thumbnail is wider than the image
   $new_width = $thumb_width;
   $new_height = $height / ($width / $thumb_width);
}

$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);

// Resize and crop
imagecopyresampled($thumb,
                   $image,
                   0 - ($new_width - $thumb_width) / 2, // Center the image horizontally
                   0 - ($new_height - $thumb_height) / 2, // Center the image vertically
                   0, 0,
                   $new_width, $new_height,
                   $width, $height);
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

In terms of putting one image on the page at a time and browse through them use previous and next button. That would require some javascript to achieve that.

There are many nice gallery that would display the image one at a time, and they already take care of the image resize issue. Take a look at [HERE](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/)